# ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to use [the CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) but the following error shows up (in JS console) when I try [the sample](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed) from the tutorial and only a texbox shows in the browser.

> ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined [Break On This Error]
>   CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' ); 
>   /xampp/ (line 13)

Note that the sample works when I try it on [my webhosting](http://bp.php5.cz/). The file ckeditor.js is accessible from the browser.

Comment: Check the console whether the ckeditor script file loaded properly. What is the URL you're trying to access your page with (on the xampp version)?

Comment: Wild guess: remove the leading slash from `/ckeditor/ckeditor.js` (so try with `ckeditor/ckeditor.js`).

Comment: Your wild guess works bažmegakapa. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the leading slash from `/ckeditor/ckeditor.js` (so try with `ckeditor/ckeditor.js`).

The leading slash means the "**root**".

So if you are using an URL like `http://bp.php5.cz/`, and then say `/ckeditor/ckeditor.js`, it will mean `http://bp.php5.cz/ckeditor/ckeditor.js`. But if your URL is `localhost/xampp/`, it will resolve to `localhost/ckeditor/ckeditor.js`, which is not what you want.

If you omit the leading slash, the relative URL will be resolved from the "current URL", so it will be correct in both cases.

The safest way would be of course to use the absolute URL.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I wonder why it works on the webhosting and not on localhost.

Comment: @Slazer I added the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I loaded the CDN script before my closing body tag, after `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' )`. Tossed it in the head and it's all good.

Answer (score 2):

If you're loading from a CDN, check that you're using the full URL, including the "http:" part.

Comment: What is CDN? When I changed the src of the script to this
<script src="http://localhost/xampp/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
then it works. I wonder why the short src (/ckeditor/ckeditor.js) does not work on localhost though.

Comment: If you took the time to check the example he posted, you would know he uses no CDN :)

Answer (score 0):

you must pay attention to the declaration of ckeditor.js. It must be before the textarea input and its initialisation

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
.
.
<input type=textarea" id="ckedit" ...
.
.
<script type="text/javascript">
 var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'teckeditor', {
.
.
```

etc. etc.

The problem is that we usually declare js scripts declaration before the

```
</body>
```

tag.

In these cases the declaration may be after the input text area and the ckedit initialisation

=> thats why you have the error message "ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same problem with Codeigniter 4, I solved it in the following code of the route

`app/Libraries/GroceryCrudEnterprise/grocerycrud/enterprise/src/GroceryCrud/Themes/Bootstrap/views/build/datagrid.php`:

Search:

```
if ($load_texteditor) {
```

Replace by:

```
if ($load_texteditor || $autoload_javascript) {
```

And that's it :)

Comment: answer is in different language