# While entering the text in CK Editor That first letter should be in capital letter and after full stop also i display capital letter in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor

I need to display first letter is capital letter and after .(full-stop) also capital letter in ck editor. but i searching process i found same thing on some code in that have the `key down` event but i tried that in java script that `key down` event is not fired how can i do this can any one suggest me to how to do this it is very need to me.

I Tried code is:

```
   var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;

editor.document.getBody().on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.data.getKeystroke() === 65 /*a*/ && isFirstLetter()) {
        // insert 'A' instead of 'a'
        editor.insertText('A');
        event.data.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

can any one suggest me to how to do this it is very need to me.

Thank you.

Comment: code is proper, what is issue? have you debugg it?

Comment: i need to while entering the text that should be capital letter i need. but it is not working in my page key down event and instance is not created is not working where i write this code can you please tell me

Comment: ok, just put your html too, maybe there is any issue.

Comment: In my html only this code ` <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor/" runat="server" Width="99%" Height="188px"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl> ` in java script i wrote the above code

Answer (score 2):

Just change condition:

`if(event.data.getKeyStroke()>== 97 && event.data.getKeyStroke() <== 122 && isFirstLetter()) {
    editor1.insertText(<findvalueofinputbox>.toUpperCase())
}`

Comment: I got This exception ` 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'CKEDITOR' is undefined `

Comment: Did you add CKEDIOR js file? This is complusory

Comment: i added CKEDIOR.js file but i am not getting.when i entering the text in ckeditor for example i enter like this " this is the code.. " while entering the "t next entering and second letter h  already entered letter "t" changed to capital letter i added all the the above code the instance is not created and ` key down` event not fired can you please tell me how to do this thank you.

Comment: Second character added automatically because we are using insert method.

Answer (score 0):

here is your mistake,

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor/" runat="server" Width="99%" Height="188px"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

your Id is CKEditor1 and you are calling instance as

```
 var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
```

so what is editor1?

it should be

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.CKEditor1;
```

try these..

Comment: I tried this but i got `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'CKEDITOR' is undefined ` this exception can you please tell me how to do this

Comment: view these : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417704/referenceerror-ckeditor-is-not-defined

Comment: can you please tell me i didn't get anything about that

Comment: in sort, your ckeditor is not placed in your page, maybe it's issue of javascript, or you missed to add ckeditors all library files, just check all and then you will have editor.

Comment: i added CKEDIOR.js file but i am not getting.when i entering the text in ckeditor for example i enter like this " this is the code.. " while entering the "t next entering and second letter h  already entered letter "t" changed to capital letter i added all the the above code the instance is not created and ` key down` event not fired can you please tell me how to do this thank you.

Comment: FIRST try to find editor, without editor you can not fire key down event. for editor you must need your ckeditor instance .

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use text transformation

```js
from: /(^|[.?!] )([a-z])$/,
                            to: function (matches) {

                                if (matches[0] == '. ') {
                                    return [null, matches[1].toUpperCase()]
                                }
                                else if (matches[0] == "") {
                                    return [null, matches[1].toUpperCase()]
                                }
                                else {
                                    return [null, null]
                                }
                                }
```